# Letter Letter Frequency

Tags: c++

I have an assignment that needs me to count the frequency of each word.From A-Z,and the length is 1-1000.

The output is depending the frequency of the character and it's ASCII value.If there are two having same frequency then will print the character which is having the smaller ASCII value.

If the input is YVPDF then the output is `68 1 70 1 86 1 89 1`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int i, j, k,temp;
int b[26] = { 0 };
int index[26] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25 };
void  fillFrequency(string str1, int freqcount[])
{
    for (string::size_type i = 0; i < str1.size(); i++)
    {
        ++(freqcount[str1[i] - 'A']);
    }
}
int main()
{
    string a;
    getline(cin, a, '\n');
    fillFrequency(a, b);
    for (j = 0; j < 26; j++)
    {
        for (k = j + 1; k < 26; k++)
        {
            int temp;
            if (b[index[j]] < b[index[k]])
            {
                temp = index[j];
                index[j] = index[k];
                index[k] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
    {
        if (b[index[i]] >0)
        {
            cout << index[i] + 'A' << " " << b[index[i]] << endl;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

finally the outcome is correct.
for YVPDF 
I have

```
68 1
70 1
80 1
86 1
89 1
```

How can I improve the efficiency?
I tried to use sort() and made a compare function,but it did not work.

```
bool compare(int i,int j)
{
    return b[index[i]] > b[index[j]];
}
```

It didn't sort the way I want.

Comment: you're supposed to include example of input that gives erroneous result, expected output and factual output

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie "YVPDF" is the input and "68 1 70 1 86 1 89 1" is the (incorrect) output.

Comment: it is always good to have some error handling, especially when I/O is concerned. E.g. entering a non-ASCII value will cause your program to crash.

Answer (score 0):

You have an UB if you input lowercase letters, because their code is rather than uppercase and you reserved only 26 positions in your array

The line return you the size of array

```
int len = sizeof(b) / sizeof(*b);
```

just use it  to push into vector? vector can be constructed from array.

Your result unreproduceable, output I get states:

```
YVPDF

21 1
13 1
0 1
7 1
2 1
```

Still incorrect, because that's not ASCII codes, that indices of letters? IF you expect ascii code in output, you have add `'A'` to `index[i]`.

```
86 1
78 1
65 1
72 1
67 1
```

Still off?

b after frequency counting: 0 0 0 **1** 0 **1** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 **1** 0 0 0 0 0 **1** 0 0 **1** 0

index before sort: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25

index after sort: 24 3 5 ***21*** 15 ***13*** 25 23 22 20 19 18 17 16 14 ***0*** 12 11 10 9 8 ***7*** 6 4 ***2*** 1

Something wrong with your approach, that kind of sorting doesn't give you result you want. It's actually one culprit:

```
if (data[i] > 0)
```

Your `data` was not sorted, it's still matches order of `b` array and you're printing wrong indices in result. I've bolded them out Actually, if you remove sorting, you'll get proper output with this line:

```
cout << index[i]+'A' << " " << data[i] << endl;
```

Results in

```
68 1
70 1
80 1
86 1
89 1
```

It's not sorted of course, so you should do something else for your strategy. E.g. use a vector of std::pair to store frequency data. Sorting of such would involve lambda which compares pair member that corresponds to frequency, but both values would be swapped at same time.

Comment: I've made some changes to the code.using the bubble sort for index and the frequency array

Answer (score 0):

There is a more or less standard approach for counting something in a container.

We can use an associative container like a `std::map`or a `std::unordered_map`. And here we associate a "key", in this case the letter to  count, with a value, in this case the count of the specific letter.

And luckily the maps have a very nice index operator`[]`. This will look for the given key and if found, return a reference to the value. If not found, the it will create a new entry with the key and return a reference to the new entry. So, in bot cases, we will get a reference to the value used for counting. And then we can simply write:

```
std::unordered_map<char,int> counter{};
for (const char c : myString) counter[c]++;
```

And that looks really intuitive.

After this operation, you have already the frequency table. Either sorted, by using a `std::map` or unsorted, but faster accessible with a `std::unordered_map`.

Often people want to sort according to the frequency. Unfortunately this is not possible with maps.

The we need to use a second container, like a ```std::vector`````which we than can sort unsing `std::sort` for any given predicate, or, we can copy the values into a container, like a `std::multiset` that implicitely orders its elements.

Then we can come up with a very compact piece of code. Because the definition of the containers is a lot of writing, we can use the `using` statment, to define easier useable names.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <type_traits>

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// Create aliases. Save typing work and make code more readable
using Pair = std::pair<char, unsigned int>;

// Standard approach for counter
using Counter = std::unordered_map<Pair::first_type, Pair::second_type>;

// Sorted values will be stored in a multiset
struct Comp { bool operator ()(const Pair& p1, const Pair& p2) const { return (p1.second == p2.second) ? p1.first<p2.first : p1.second>p2.second; } };
using Rank = std::multiset<Pair, Comp>;
// ------------------------------------------------------------


// Function to get the rank of letters in a string
Rank getRank(const std::string& str) {

    Counter counter;
    for (const char c : str) counter[c]++;

    return { counter.begin(), counter.end() };
}

// Test / Driver Code
int main() {

    if (std::string userString{}; std::getline(std::cin, userString))

    for (const auto& [letter, count] : getRank(userString))
        std::cout << (int)letter << ' ' << count << ' ';
}
```

---

To be compiled with C++17